# how do I write a MySQL delete with multiple jeft joins

Tags: mysql, left-join, sql-delete

I'm using MySQL 5.5.37.  I would like to write a DELETE statement where I say delete from table "c" if c has no matching rows in either table A or B.  So I tried this

```
delete from classroom c 
left join lesson_plan_classroom lpc 
on c.id = lpc.classroom_id 
left join response r on c.id = r.classroom_id 
where r.classroom_id is null 
and lpc.classroom_id is null 
and c.enabled = 0;
```

Unfortunately, the above doesn't work and dies with the error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check 
the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near 'c left join sb_lesson_plan_classroom 
lpc on c.id = lpc.classroom_id left join sb' at line 1
```

What is the right way to structure the delete statement to incorporate both left joins?

Comment: there is no `sb_lesson_plan_classroom` in your SQL statement, are you sure this is the right one?

Comment: You mean something like `DELETE from c WHERE somefield NOT IN (SELECT stuff FROM a LEFT JOIN b)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `DELETE` query syntax to be like below. Since you are declaring a table alias `c`, you should use it in `DELETE` statement.

```
delete c from classroom c
left join lesson_plan_classroom lpc on c.id = lpc.classroom_id 
left join response r on c.id = r.classroom_id 
where r.classroom_id is null 
and lpc.classroom_id is null 
and c.enabled = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your post and corrected what appears to be spelling mistakes, but perhaps 'incoprorate' is an apt description of your current SQL.

Consider:

```
DELETE from classroom c 
WHERE c.enabled is false
AND c.id NOT IN (
   SELECT r.classroom_id
   FROM response r
)
AND c.id NOT IN (
    SELECT lpc.classroom_id
    FROM lesson_plan_classroom lpc)
```

Comment: THis doesn't seem to be working.  It deleted zero rows whereas when I write this query, "select count(*) FROM classroom c left join lesson_plan_classroom lpc on c.id = lpc.classroom_id left join response r on c.id = r.classroom_id where c.enabled = 0;", it select thousands of rows.

Comment: But the logic of that select query is quite different from  `if c has no matching rows in either table A or B`; it will return all the rows in classroom at least once.